# Why does the same ratio of noise variances generate the same decomposition result with the Kalman filter?

Tags: seasonality, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time and hope there is someone help me out!!!

The model is the structural state space model:
$$
y_t = T_t + S_t + I_t \qquad I_t \sim N(0, \sigma_I^2)
$$
$$
T_{t+1} = T_t + \eta_{t} \qquad \eta_t \sim N(0, \sigma_T^2)
$$
$$
S_{t+1} = - \sum_{j=1}^{s-1} S_{t+1-j} + \omega_t \qquad \omega_t \sim N(0, \sigma_S^2)
$$

After some tests I found (with R package KFAS) : for the same dataset, as long as the ratio $\sigma_I^2 : \sigma_T^2 : \sigma_S^2$ does not change, the decomposition won't change. Now I want to prove it with rigorous steps but didn't find satisfying solutions after searching. Is there anyone know how to prove it?

Much appreciated:)

Comment: Hi: I don't know how to prove it but it has to do with the coefficient estimates being functions of the signal to noise ratios. In fact, the updating equations can probably be written in terms of those rations. That might be the best method for proving it, namely show that the updating equations in a KF can be written such that they are functions of the signal to noise ratios.

Comment: @mlofton Hi thanks for your comment. Actually I found some papers that give this conclusion but without convincing derivation. And I am glad to know this ratio called signal-to-noise ratio, thanks!

Comment: Hi: yeah, sometimes these people believe that things are so "obvious" that they don't need to show the proof. I've had the same problem. It should be somewhere but I looked and couldn't find anything. Maybe if you take say the random walk + noise  model and show it for that simpler case, then maybe the generalization is more obvious ? I'm not skilled at derivations or I'd try it myself.

Comment: @mlofton Actually I already proved it for the local level model and have seen the similar/relevant proof somewhere. I guess I would come back to solve the multivariate version in the future... it should not be very had although I have spent much time on it.

Comment: That's great. I wish that I knew where the general case was. I may google around or look in some book. It's got to be somewhere I would think. Or, if you work with some KF expert, I bet he-she could show it for you ?

Comment: Hi: I was looking a little more and the kalman gain update is the reason what you said is true. I still don't have a proof but this paper looks like a good start if you're interested. Only the first couple of pages are related but they seem pretty relevant. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11618.pdf

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment very much! Unfortunately I don't have an expert around me. I will consider the paper you recommended later! Thanks again！@mlofton